# add a string list to a viewmodel list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, generic-collections

```
public ActionResult LatestNews()
{
    using (NDTMS2UtilsEntities newsEntities = new NDTMS2UtilsEntities())
    {
        var newsItems = newsEntities.News.OrderByDescending(ni => ni.DateCreated).Take(5);

        int n = 0;
        var urlList = new List<string>();
        var newsModel = new List<NewsManagerViewModel>();

        while (n < newsItems.Count())
        {
            string newsUrl =
                new Uri(Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Host + ":3153/News/Index/" + n).ToString();

            urlList.Add(newsUrl);

            n++;
        }
        newsModel = newsItems.Select(item => new NewsManagerViewModel()
        {
            Title = item.Title,
            NewsContent = item.NewsContent, 
            DateCreated = (DateTime) item.DateCreated
        }).ToList();

        return PartialView(newsModel);
    }
}
```

the code above creates a list of the top 5 news items ordered by date descending, I have created two lists one is a list of URLs called `urlList` and another which contains the news items called `newsModel`.

`urlList` is a list of strings and `newsModel` is a list  of the `NewsManagerViewModel`, in each list there are exactly 5 elements.

I am looking for a way of combining these two lists so that each URL is matched with each news item.

currently if I combine the lists using `newsModel.AddRange(urlList)` all of the news items have the same id at the end (4) whereas my requirement is for the first news item to have id of 0 and the last an id of 4.

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating them separately, you can create them at once in a single `for`.

```
public ActionResult LatestNews()
{
    using (NDTMS2UtilsEntities newsEntities = new NDTMS2UtilsEntities())
    {
        var newsItems = newsEntities.News.OrderByDescending(ni => ni.DateCreated).Take(5).ToList();

        var newsModel = new List<NewsManagerViewModel>();

        for(int n = 0; n < newsItems.Count(); n++)
        {
            string newsUrl = new Uri(Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Host + ":3153/News/Index/" + n).ToString();
            var item = newsItems[n];
            var newsManagerModel = new NewsManagerViewModel()
            {
                Title = item.Title,
                NewsContent = item.NewsContent, 
                DateCreated = (DateTime) item.DateCreated,
                NewsUrl = newsUrl // add the url
            }
            newsModel.Add(newsManagerModel)
        }

        return PartialView(newsModel);
    }
}
```